# Spivak Calculus Question 6 a) Prove that if 0 < x < y, then x^n < y^n, n = 1,2,3,....

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Looked up a solution and the result I found looked nothing like what I had, and so I was wondering if a solution along these lines would work?

I tried to solve the following problem as follows:
[image: A problem from Spivak Calculus]]

$0 \le x < y \implies  [x \in P \land (y/x > 1)] \lor x = 0$

Case 1: $x = 0,x^n = 0$ for any nonnegative n or 0, and since 0 < y it follows $x^n = 0 < y^n$.

Case 2: $x \neq 0 \land x < y.$ If x < y yet again it implies y/x > 1

$x^n < y^n$, we divide both sides by $x^n (x \neq 0)$ and get $1 < (y/x)^n$. Since we know y/x > 1 it follows $(y/x)^n$ to any nonnegative power (except 0, which we don't consider) will still be bigger than 1.

It feels like it should work.

Comment: "Since we know y/x > 1 it follows (y/x)^n" I think in this exercise you are asked to prove it. The "$n=1,2,3,\dots$" should suggest a method ;-)

Comment: Is it a problem? I had noted it while making the calculation, but while writing the proof I only use the y/x > 1 in case 2, where we know x != 0.

Comment: Oh I see, makes sense. Edited. Thank you :)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069716). But not considered as a duplicate, since your question was about your own proof (I answered it in my first comment above).

Comment: I see it does make sense. Would the issue with this "proof" be that I am not really using first principles?

Comment: That is what I think.

Comment: Ok I see, this makes sense. Thanks a lot Anne!. :)

Comment: Why does the title say '$x"\le y"$' while the content says '$x^n < y^n$'?

Comment: For some reason when I copy-pasted it, it pasted it as ", I don't see the equal tho?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very well suited for mathematical induction... The induction base is trivial, as $0\leq x < y \Rightarrow 0 \leq x < y$. We just need to show that when $0 \leq x < y$ and $x^n < y^n$, we also have that $0 \leq x^{n+1} < y^{n+1}$. This is immediate, since
$$
x^{n+1} = x x^n < x y^n < y y^n = y^{n+1}
$$

In the previous inequalities I first used the induction hypothesis and then the given fact that $x < y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is more natural (to me) than the other solutions I saw.

Comment: Agreed about induction. Chapter 2 introduces inductive arguments. The placement of this problem (and a few others) before that chapter, is a bit unfortunate.